# Manipulating images via javascript, very simple

Tags: javascript, html

edit:

thanks a lot ya'll. Have a great night/day

---

All I'm trying to do is have javascript change the image src in a table cell by checking the id of the cell.

I have looked at every single related question on stack overflow and their solution. For some reason, my code won't work. Most likely syntax/lack of sleep issue

This js script in a table, located right above the  src I'm trying to change depending on things:

```
<script>
function getImage(){  
return "http://i.imgur.com/s5WKBjy.png"; //i literally just want to see if this works and it isn't
}  
document.onload = function(){  
    document.getElementById('homeimage').src = getImage();  
};  
</script>  

  <td colspan="3"><img style="width:110px;height:128px;" id = "homeimage" onload="getImage()"></td>   


 <td colspan = "3"><img style="width:150px;height:128px;" id = "homeimage"></td>
```

neither of the above work. With the onload = "getImage()" and without. Am I being dumb? There's got to be something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: You should bind the onload event on window instead.

Comment: id is unique.multiple elements cannot have same id

Comment: I've already pointed out to that in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As if you don't want to use any `ID` the you can use this method, 
This code works for n number td's in your table....

```js
window.onload = function()
{  
    
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
    tds = rows[0].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var n=0; n<tds.length;n++)
    {
        tds[n].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = getImage();
    }
}

function getImage(){ 
 return "http://i.imgur.com/s5WKBjy.png";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3"><img style="width:110px;height:128px;"></td>   
     <td colspan = "3"><img style="width:150px;height:128px;"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: i like this idea of not using ids, but copying your code into mine doesn't do anything. Do you have to declare var tds?

Comment: this depends on your table layout, In this code i'm fetching the td's of only first tr in table, can i see your table layout so that i can tell you the way how to get all the td's that you want... @JoeKnight

Comment: [HERE IS THE WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t56dh8oe/) @JoeKnight check this fiddle my friend, you just need to change this line `tds = rows[0].getElementsByTagName("td");` with this `tds = rows[2].getElementsByTagName("td");`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two images with the same id. Name one `homeimage1` and the other one `homeimage2` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use same `id` more than once in a single web page. Use different ids.
2nd change `doucment.onload` to `window.onload`

```js
function getImage(){  
 return "http://i.imgur.com/s5WKBjy.png";
}  
window.onload = function(){  
    document.getElementById('homeimageA').src = getImage();
    document.getElementById('homeimageB').src = getImage();
}
```

```html
  <td colspan="3"><img style="width:110px;height:128px;" id = "homeimageA" onload="getImage()"></td>   


 <td colspan = "3"><img style="width:150px;height:128px;" id = "homeimageB"></td>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I answered, why do you answered than the exact same?

Comment: @your answer is incomplete. Even if we use different id's it not works.. untill we move code from `document.onload` to `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

Things to note:

1. You have duplicate IDs, where IDs  <del>are</del>  should be unique.
2. You should use `encodeURIComponent()` to return the url value.
3. You don't have to use `onload` on the image itself.
4. You should bind the `onload` event on window object, that will do.
5. Before set the src just `decodeURIComponent()` to return value.

---

```
<td colspan="3"><img style="width:110px;height:128px;" id="homeimage1"></td>   
<td colspan = "3"><img style="width:150px;height:128px;" id="homeimage2"></td>
```

Now changes in js:

```
<script>
   function getImage(){  
      return encodeURIComponent("http://i.imgur.com/s5WKBjy.png"); //i literally just want to see if this works and it isn't
   }  
   window.onload = function(){  
       document.getElementById('homeimage').src = decodeURIComponent(getImage());  
   };  
</script>
```